# OV2640 Camera example with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, camera

I searched for ov2640 with Arduino examples but only I could get the examples of Arducam. So I'm trying [**this**](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/how-to-use-ov7670-camera-module-with-arduino) example with [**OV2640**](https://robokits.co.in/sensors/camera-module/ov2640-2-megapixel-camera-module-support-esp32-cam-development-board?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkuP9BRCkARIsAKGLE8XUbVp3GJtFd655gelnjPUf-wYwZ8LTPsn8y2tbXAyuAQXl0prg-r4aAkoYEALw_wcB) camera. As ov7670 and ov2640 have similar pinouts. But I'm not getting the image(output)(But I got the output while using [**OV7670**](https://robokits.co.in/sensors/ov7670-vga-sensor-camera-breakout-board) camera). I don't know why I'm not getting the output. Someone please let me know where do I go wrong(Reference image attached) and please let me know any other example you may know.

Thank you,
Roshan

[image: OV2640 Camera][image: Connections][image: Circuit Board][image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: There's no datasheet at the link you provided. From what I've been able to find out, the OV2640 works at 1.2V while it looks like you're supplying it with 1.8V. That might be a problem. Output I/O voltages might also be too low to be recognized by the Arduino.

Comment: As I seen in other project OV2640 camera with PIC microcontroller. They used to supply 1.8V. They used MIC550 IC to regulate(1.8V) the voltage. I used here lm317.                       https://www.circuitvalley.com/2019/06/opensource-diy-usb-webcam-ov7670-ov2640-pic32-USB-UVC-Video-device-class.html